# Почему здесь не происходит переопределение членов класса?

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>

class Captcha {
private:
    uint16_t m_length = 1;
    uint16_t m_length_max = 1;
    uint16_t m_length_min = 1;
public:
    Captcha()
        : m_length{ 0 }, m_length_max{ 0 }, m_length_min{ 0 }
    {}

    Captcha(int a)
    {
        Captcha();
    }

};


int main()
{
    Captcha cap(1);
}
```

Почему здесь не происходит переопределение? В этом случае выполняется конструктор с параметрами `int`, сначала он инициализирует переменные члены класса единицами, потом выполняется тело конструктора и вызывается конструктор выше, он в свою очередь инициализирует с помощью списка инициализации (не присваивает).

Comment: Вы просто создаёте новый временный объект внутри тела конструктора, а не делегируете инициализацию другому конструктору. Надо в списке инициализации (после `:`) писать для делегации.

Comment: @tocic Временный объект - это объект, неявно созданный компилятором, у которого нету имени, или это объект с именем и маленькой областью видимости?

Comment: Вот здесь `Captcha();` создаётся временный объект типа `Captcha` без имени, время жизни которого заканчивается в конце выражения. Т.к. у конструктора и деструктора нет side-эффектов, скорее всего, компилятор не будет генерить никакого кода для создания этого объекта. См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234673/6944845.